# Installing sliding door shades

Tags: mounting, sliding-glass-door

I recently moved into a house with sliding doors in the back of the house. In the garage I found the sliding shades that normally go with sliding doors, but I do not see any way to mount the rail to the wall. I must be missing some pieces and when I went to Home Depot the guy advised me to drill screws through the rail and into the wall. Needless to say I am looking for alternative solutions hence I am seeking advice from the internet hive mind here. Naturally there are countless things I "could do" as a jury-rigged solution (metal shelf hangers in the wall, putting the rail on those and hoping things work out), but I am hoping someone could point me to an optimized solution. Note I cannot tell what brand of shades this product is.

The rail's dimensions are 1 and 1/2' by 1 and 1/4'. fwiw.

Below you can see the rail is meant to snap into the plastic hooks, but beyond that there is nothing to attach to the wall.

[image: Railing and clip]

[image: Close up of clip]

Comment: Should be a few metal L shape brackets(there are on mine) that mount the rail to the wall.  The brackets have the rail stand away from the wall, so that guy gave bad advice.  Need some space for the shades to move/turn.  A door/window/shade shop might have better advice/parts.  The brackets do look like mini shelf hangers.

Comment: I believe that you may be missing the valence. It's the part that mounts to the wall and supports the vertical blinds, then the clear plastic brackets snap into that, then the front cover attaches to the plastic brackets to hide all the mechanism. Is the valence already attached to the wall? Can you find markings anywhere to identify the manufacturer? You may have to get parts for this particular brand/model.

Comment: The blinds that I have had, the plastic attached to the frame it’s kind of flimsy but it only needs enough to support the plastic as it’s for looks and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the notes about the metal shelf brackets. I gave it a look and there is simply nothing in my garage that would do the trick, so I will likely go back to home depot to get something similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supposing by "sliding shades" you mean "vertical blinds"
That plastic clip and assembly in your last photo is for the valence, a decorative cover for the mechanism.  It is only strong enough to support it's own weight, not the the blinds.

As alluded to in one of the comments, the rails should be hung on metal L brackets that you would screw into the wall at several points along the rail.  Look harder for parts.  But generic L brackets would work, the only tricky part it attaching the rail without interfering with the sliding mechanism. There is often some type of clip supplied.

Here is a video from one vendor showing the process for their product.
[Installing Vertical Blinds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLCyCmOhTe0)

Comment: @user3782816 please take the [tour] for the proper way to say "thanks".